# can't access elements after jQuerymobile page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, navigateurl

I created a simple example to illustrate my problem here: https://github.com/kanesee/jqm-page-state

Basically, I have page1.html, which has a div with id=content and I change its color to red.
I have a page2.html, which has a div with id=content and I change its color to green.

When I go to page1, the color of the text in the div is red, as expected.
When I go to page2, the color of the text in the div is green, as expected.

I have a simple anchor href from page1 that goes to page2. After clicking it, page2 loads and the text inside the div changes accordingly. But the color of the text is unchanged. It's black.

I've been told that when ajax handles page navigation, the page state remains in the original pages context. So when I go to page2, I'm actually still  on page1 but part of the content in page2 is loaded into the DOM.

What do I need to do to get around this?

Is there a proper solution? Or even a simple one that just loads page2 entirely brand new as if I typed it into my address bar by hand?

Comment: Btw, regarding your last sentence "_loads page2 entirely brand new_" in this case you need to disable Ajax by adding either `data-ajax=false` or `rel=external` to anchor.

Comment: Can I do this programmatically?

Comment: `location.href = "page2.html"`

Comment: Thanks @Omar! I can always count on you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same `id` for both pages and both pages are inside the same DOM as Ajax is enabled. You have to specify which *element* to target and in which page.

`$("#content")` will return first element in DOM, hence, you need to use *page events* to target that element inside current page or the page you're about to navigate to. This can be achieve by using any almost all *page events*.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
   var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
   if (activePage.attr("data-url") == "page2.html") {
      // target content within active page
      // Or activePage.find("#content").css...
      $("#content", activePage).css({ color : "green" });
   }
});
```

The above is a basic example; there are more advanced solutions.

Comment: This makes sense and it was my initial theory based on what you said in my other posts. So I can either make sure my id's are unique are across all pages or reference this activePage in all my code. Thank you!

Comment: @kane you're welcome. Using unique `id` is always recommended, however, if you use classes, you'll need to reference them based on page containing them.

Comment: Quick update: activePage.attr('data-url') returns "indexpage" for the initial page you load up. This may be problematic because if you load page1 first and then navigate around, then page1 will be known as "indexpage". But if you visit page2 first, then it's known as "indexpage". So unless you have a specific landing page for users, this solution has some complications, I think

Comment: @kane you can overcome this by adding a unique `id` for each page, or use [`$.mobile.path.get(URL)`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.path.get/) to determine which page is currently viewed based on URL.