# Uncaught TypeError - checkboxradio("refresh")

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-mobile, webforms

Every way I can think of to use `("#chkBox1").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");` leads to errors. In Chrome I get `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`. I load this script in an external file after jQuery and before JQM, & DateBox. I use ASP.NET Web Forms. I disabled client-side validation of many validation controls, which helped with another problem.

I reviewed possible solutions including ensuring that there is [only one reference](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/typeerror-this-element-prop-is-not-a-function) to jQuery. I'm using the documentation from [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop-propertyName-value) website. I have a working JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jinhale/3KX63/#base), but I can't seem to get the checkboxradio widget to work in a web form. Is there a way to fix this error? Any idea what causes this error?

---- edit ----

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {

    if ($("#chkBox1:checked")) {
        sessionStorage.isHBH = true;
    } else {
        sessionStorage.isHBH = true;
    }

    if ($("#chkBox1").length) {
        if (sessionStorage.isHBH) {
            $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", true).checkboxradio("refresh");
        } else {
            $("#chkBox1").prop("checked", false).checkboxradio("refresh");
        }
    }        
});
```

After eliminating the client-side JavaScript code I still get an error on the refresh part but only a few steps into the process. Also, if I refresh the page the checkbox is selected but never again. Is there a way to reliably and dynamically change the checked status of a checkbox using JQM?

Comment: Is `chkBox1` really the ID on the client? Are you sure it doesn't end up being something like `chkBox1`? I have little trouble using jQuery and jQuery Mobile in my ASP.NET applications. Your solution you posted seems to be based on a failed understanding of how Web Forms works.

Comment: You're probably calling refresh function before checkbox is created.

Comment: @mason I'm sure the ID didn't change because it is plain HTML + JavaScript.

Comment: @Omar I'm using the "pagechange" event. Should I do something different?

Comment: @haleonj You're saying you're sure the ID didn't change based on some assumption. **Look** at the resulting HTML and verify. Don't assume.

Comment: `pagechange` is deprecated and isn't of help. Use other page events. It depends on when do you want to check it?

Comment: @mason It didn't change, and I know how to use [id*='nameOfID'] in the times when the ID does change.

Comment: I got the page event information from http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagechange/ I'll look elsewhere.

Comment: Please update your question. Problems asking why something doesn't work should include enough information to reduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "pagecreate" doesn't do the job either. Just to be clear the error message is gone the only problem is that the checkbox doesn't dynamically get checked.

Comment: So now I just noticed I get the same error on submit.

Comment: Then you aren't targeting the checkbox _if_ you're using the same id in a different page in DOM http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235047/cant-access-elements-after-jquerymobile-page-change/24235161#24235161

Comment: @Omar thank you for the help. Using classes instead of IDs worked wonders. The strange thing is that while looking at the source there is only one element with that ID.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing up a question for this problem when I tested disabling *every* validation control's client script functionality not just a few. That fixed my problem instantly.

The origin of the problem must be that ASP.NET Web Forms is being too helpful by half. Validation controls inject a lot of JavaScript that interferes with the custom script and in particular interferes with this checkboxradio widget's code.

I suspect many strange jQuery and JQM problems can be solved by disabling this sort of "help" that Web Forms imposes on us by default.

-- EDIT --

Problems cropped up latter, but were fixed using "pagecontainershow" as the event